# How to create a SEO friendly .htaccess that does not conflict with php files and user handling file that uses "GET" request

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My root folder structure is as follows:

[image]

I have an **index.php** as the home page and I want it to **load when i simply go to my domain** (ex: http://example.com)

Then, I have **user.php** page that **GET** data and show the user. current url http://example.com/user.php?u=johndoe

I want it to be http://example.com/johndoe

and I want it to identify other php files and folders **without any conflict** with above structure.

(http://example.com/about not interpret as http://example.com/user.php?u=about  or http://example.com/folder as http://example.com/user.php?u=folder)

I appreciate a **SEO friendly** answer. Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using a lightweight framework like slim php to handle your requests?  It'll do what you need it to do, and it should be fairly trivial to implement alongside the code you've already written.

Comment: You will probably struggle if you alias `http://example.com/johndoe -> http://example.com/user.php?u=johndoe`. This would need a "catch-all" and thus you would be assuming that anything not specifically recognised is a user. In six months time, when you want to add another object (e.g. groups) then you'll be stuck - unless you don't mind doing various database calls to find out what type of object something is.

Comment: It is much better to use the format of `http://example.com/u/johndoe` or `http://example.com/user/johndoe` so you know what kind of object the user wants (and so you have room for further expansion). You can write some Apache mod_rewrite directives to accomplish this (see the suggested duplicate).

Comment: I agree with @Emma's tag edits, so I have restored them. I have also removed voting advice from this post, which is not of interest to most readers (most readers do not have an account). I recommend being careful about rolling back good edits, and I would note that it takes a bit of experience in order to know what a good edit looks like.